# Что такое referencing outlet?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios, objective-c

Я недавно установил Xcode 3.1, и мне непонятен один момент в Interface Builder - referencing outlet. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что это такое и как они связаны с остальным кодом приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это сделано для связи объекта в заголовочных файлах с объектом интерфейса - так называемое делегирование объектов!
допустим в хедере есть UIWebView *browser;

browser можно связать с каким то UIWebView в интерфейс билдере - и ему будут сразу доступны список методов определённых для browser в коде проекта.